# Resources for learning Verilog

Tags: microcontroller, verilog, fpga

I'm new to Verilog. Can someone suggest a learning resource, book, video, blog or anything that they had a good personal experience with and helped them learn it faster?

If it helps, I have experience programming in several high-level languages, but have no experience programming in C.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of [Stuart Sutherland](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/)'s [papers](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers.php) and [books](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/books.php).  He has an exceptionally deep understanding of the language and it really comes through in his writing.

As with any language, the best way to learn is by reading other people's code.  To that end, consider [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/) and [OpenSPARC](http://www.opensparc.net/).  If you have tools from Xilinx or Altera installed, consider looking through the source code for their IP cores (some cores will be obfuscated, but many are not).

Answer (score 4):

Learning Verilog is very far from high-level languages. The syntax has been inspired by C, yes, but designing electronics (be it using VHDL or Verilog) is very different from writing software.

Having said that, I suppose that you have found the obvious through Google. For instance this [tutorial](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/veritut.html), and them [main Verilog site](http://www.verilog.com/). The latter lists books and contains a free tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Verilog, first and foremost, is a hardware description language. So you need to have some background in digital design (or at least get yourself familiar with it). Also, the answer to your question will depend on the reason you want to learn Verilog:

- are you going to do some FPGA development? If yes, [Xilinx](http://xilinx.com) and [Altera](http://altera.com) have lots of good Verilog examples and other learning resources. You can install free tools (with some limitations)
- are you going to do ASIC development or verification? If yes, browse [Synopsys](http://Synopsys.com) or [Cadence](http://Cadence.com) sites.
- if you just want to learn the language then you'd need at least a simulator to do anything useful with your Verilog code. Look at [Icarus Verilog](http://www.icarus.com/eda/verilog/) simulator.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good text books out there.  Online tutorials can introduce the major concepts but there are far fewer hardware engineers using Verilog than there are programmers writing software.  You won't get far trying to learn from the few web sites out there.

Of course, there is no point in learning Verilog if you aren't very familiar with digital logic design principles.  Verilog is a modeling language, after all, and it is necessary to understand the hardware to model it properly.

Answer (score 0):

"Verilog HDL" by Samir Palnitkar is an easy-to-read, introductory book for Verilog.  I found it useful when I was learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that your start with the book 'FPGA prototyping by verilog examples pong p. chu'

[FPGA prototyping by verilog example](http://www.scribd.com/doc/65164903/eBook-Chu-FPGA-Pro-to-Typing-Using-Verilog-Examples/)

This book uses all synthesizable codes. The most important thing when programming with HDL (Hardware descriptive language) is that you have to keep what hardware are you making in FPGA with your verilog code statement. For example you make a mux when you use assign statement e.t.c.

You will be thinking hardware.

Answer (score 0):

check this out. This can help write good verilog code with interactive syntax corrections. VGuru is first of its kind Learn-Practice-Teach platform. On the mobile device with less number of key strokes, we can complete a verilog code. Just by a click we can create testbench. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=skand+vlsi